# Debugger says that: 'request for member 'getValue' in 'body1' which is of non-class type 'bod2d...it´s line 15

Tags: c++

//at first my cpp
//I´m also not sure about the line with input.push_back.The main aim is take the values for x1,y1 etc.. store to push_back and draw a line but I have problem to initialize objects in my class 
I originally want to use vector to store values but if there are some better way to do so it doesn´t matter

```
#include <iostream>
#include "bod2d.h"
#include "playpen.h"
#include <vector>

using namespace std ;
using namespace fgw ;

int main()
{
 playpen paper ;
 double x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3 ;
      cout << " Zadejte souřadnice bodu 1[x,y] bodu 2[x,y] a bodu 3[x,y] " << endl ;
    bod2d body1(double x1,double y1,double x2,double y2,double x3,double y3) ;
    body1.getValue ();  //HERE IS THE PROBLEM

      input.push_back(x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3) ;

      drawline( paper , souradnice x1 , souradnice y1 , souradnice x2 , souradnice y2 , souradnice x3 , souradnice y3 , black) ;

 paper.display();

header file //my header file should be ok

#ifndef BOD2D_H_INCLUDED
#define BOD2D_H_INCLUDED
#include "playpen.h"
#include <cmath>
#include <C:\Users\Aleš\Desktop\Codeblocks\Projekty\dalsikody\kreslenilinie.cpp>

class bod2d
{
    private:

       double souradnice x1 ;
       double soouradnice y1 ;
       double souradnice x2 ;
       double souradnice y2 ;
       double souradnice x3 ;
       double souradnice y3 ;

public:
      bod2d (double x,double y) {
      setValue(x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3) ;

      }
       void drawline(fgw::playpen &, double souradnice x1,double souradnice y1 , double souradnice x2 , double souradnice y2 , double souradnice x3 , double souradnice y3,fgw::hue)

       void drawline(fgw::playpen & paper,double souradnice x1,double souradnice y1 , double souradnice x2 , double souradnice y2 , double souradnice x3 , double souradnice y3 fgw::hue odstin )

           for(double i(0) ; i!= sqrt[(souradnice x2-souradnice x1^2)+[(souradnice y2-souradnice y1^2)],i++ )
{
    paper.plot(souradnice x1,souradnice y1,black) ;
}

       for(double i(0) ; i!= sqrt[(souradnice x3-souradnice x2^2)+[(souradnice y3-souradnice y2^2)],i++ )

       {
         paper.plot(souradnice x2,souradnice y2,black) ;

       }

       for(double i(0) ; i!= sqrt[(souradnice x1-souradnice x3^2)+[(souradnice y1-souradnice y3^2)],i++ )

          {
              (paper.plot(souradnice x3,souradnice y3,black) ;
          }
    void setValue(double x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3)
    {
        souradnice x1 = x1 ;
        souradnice y1 = y1 ;
        souradnice x2 = x2 ;
        souradnice y2 = y2 ;
        souradnice x3 = x3 ;
        souradnice y3 = y3 ;

    }
    double getValue (double,double,double,double,double,double)
    {
        return  souradnice x1 ;
        soouradnice y1 ;
        souradnice x2 ;
        souradnice y2 ;
        souradnice x3 ;
        souradnice y3 ;
      }
      }
#endif // BOD2D_H_INCLUDED
```

Comment: `bod2d body1(double x1,double y1,double x2,double y2,double x3,double y3) ` is a function declaration, not a construction of a `bod2d` object. If you remove all the `double`s, it might work better (or not, as there seems to be no 6 parameter constructor).